# Gmail and PHP MAIL function

Tags: php, gmail

I have a small problem that i cannot for the life of me seem to solve. I have a php script which takes some user data and processes it and sends an email to admin and an email to the user with an activation key. This is all fine and dandy, but the problem is GMAIL accounts. The user gets the email no problem but if it is a GMAIL account there is no mail in the inbox or spam box. Just wondering anyone might have any solutions.

Comment: so across the board, NO gmail accounts get your email? Maybe your host is blacklisted, and your mail is just flat out banned? Is your server blacklisted? Have you checked? Also what is your /var/log/ mail queue result? Does gmail accept the mail?

Comment: just like @Jakub suggested, if it works fine with all other email accounts, then it is most likely because your host/domain has ended up being blacklisted for some reason, it might also be because of the link(s) inside your message or other text within. Try removing all your links and just write something. A sentence or two (no jibberish). And see if it works or not. It'll most likely not, but except for being blacklisted, it's the only other thing that could be the cause as far as I know

Comment: Are You sure PHP server is configured for sending eMail? What eMail domains are working? Something other than localhost?

Comment: Hey guys , you are right :) I have just heard that my clients servers were hacked and some dubious mails were sent from the mailserver and it looks like the host has been blacklisted. Guys thanks for that really appreciate it.

Comment: Posted it as an answer so that you can accept and "close" the Q. If @Jakub returns, simply uncheck my answer and check his as he was first to suggest it

Answer (score 2):

*moved from my comment:*

so across the board, NO gmail accounts get your email? Maybe your host is blacklisted, and your mail is just flat out banned? Is your server blacklisted? Have you checked? Also what is your /var/log/ mail queue result? Does gmail accept the mail?

**Some tools, check if you were blacklisted here:**

- http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
- http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check
- Some more info on getting un-blacklisted: http://www.isipp.com/resources/am-i-blacklisted/

> Be aware that sometimes it may take awhile to get de-listed, I had one
>   server act up, and was blocked by hotmail, for a few months even after
>   all places removed my ip.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some SMTP php implementation, which can reveal possible problem.It will contact gmail servers directly without passing them to MTA.

Also note that gmail uses SSL enalbed SMTP servers on port 465 or 587.

On other way, take a look at this : http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-mail-and-gmail